# Mongoose userSchema.pre("save") Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wrote a method to update a user in my application and everything works correctly there. In addition, I wrote some code that fires before the document is saved and it isn't functioning correctly.

The point of the code is to determine if the user modified their password. If they didn't, simply call next(). If they did, bcrypt will hash the password.

**Here's the code in my controller where I'm doing the update:**

```
// @desc    Update user by ID
// @route   PUT /api/users/:id
// @access  Private
const updateUserById = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // Destructure body content from request
    const {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        username,
        email,
        role,
        manager,
        learningStyle,
        departments,
        facility,
        company,
        isActive,
    } = req.body;
    // Search the database for the user
    const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    // Check to ensure the user was found. Else, respond with 404 error
    if (user) {
        // Update information accordingly
        user.firstName = firstName || user.firstName;
        user.lastName = lastName || user.lastName;
        user.username = username || user.username;
        user.email = email || user.email;
        user.role = role || user.role;
        user.manager = manager || user.manager;
        user.learningStyle = learningStyle || user.learningStyle;
        user.departments = departments || user.departments;
        user.facility = facility || user.facility;
        user.company = company || user.company;
        user.isActive = isActive === undefined ? user.isActive : isActive;
        // Save user to the database with updated information
        const updatedUser = await user.save();
        // Send the updated user to the client
        res.json(updatedUser);
    } else {
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error("User not found");
    }
});
```

**Here's my User model code:**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        firstName: {
            // The user's first name
            required: true,
            type: String,
            trim: true,
        },
        lastName: {
            // The user's last name
            required: true,
            type: String,
            trim: true,
        },
        username: {
            // The user's username - user can create their own
            required: true,
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true,
        },
        email: {
            // The user's email
            required: false,
            trim: true,
            lowercase: true,
            unique: true,
            type: String,
        },
        password: {
            // The user's encrypted password (bcrypt hash)
            required: true,
            type: String,
        },
        role: {
            // The user's role - drives what they're able to do within the application
            required: true,
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Role",
        },
        manager: {
            // The user's manager
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: false,
            ref: "User",
        },
        learningStyle: {
            // The user's learning style (after assessment is taken)
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: false,
            ref: "LearningStyle",
        },
        departments: [
            // The departments the user belongs to (used to drive what the user sees)
            // Example: Finishing, Shipping, Printing
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: false,
                ref: "Department",
            },
        ],
        facility: {
            // The facility the user works at. Example: Austin Facility
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: false,
            ref: "Facility",
        },
        company: {
            // The company the user works for. Example: Microsoft
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: "Company",
        },
        isActive: {
            required: true,
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

// Match user's password using bcrypt
userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (enteredPassword) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password);
};

// Generate user's encrypted password on save
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
    // Check to see if password is modified. If it is, encrypt it. If not, execute next();
    if (!this.isModified("password")) {
        console.log("Does this run?");
        next();
    }
    console.log("Does this run as well?");
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

I have:

- Added two console logs, both of which fire (see userSchema.pre("save")) in model.
- Tried to prevent the encryption from firing by checking if password is modified
- Tried dropping the entire users collection and starting over
- Another application from a course with the exact same approach working fine

Notice in my controller I am NOT updating the password at all. Yet, every time I use Postman to send a PUT request and modify even the name, the password gets hashed again and both console logs fire.

Answer (score 1):

The "save" middleware is calling `next()` but continuing on to complete the function. Use `return` or `else` to guard the rest of the code.

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
    // Check to see if password is modified. If it is, encrypt it. If not, execute next();
    if (!this.isModified("password")) {
        // Finish here
        return next();
    }
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});
```

Comment: I should add that on my other project where I used the same method everything works fine. Not sure what is going on there.

Comment: `next` will let mongoose continue on and save the document. Maybe it's a race? if the document writes before bcrypt can finish the salt/hash it's ok. You've just been lucky, or not noticed when it has occurred in the other project.

Comment: Thank you very much, Matt! I suppose the code I followed from my course was a bit flawed. Greatly appreciate the additional clarity and learning opportunity.